# Error al leer las rutas en cpanel con proyecto laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, cpanel

subí mi proyecto Laravel a un cpanel en el servidor local me carga y funciona todo correctamente pero cuando lo subo mi CSS, JS no se lee y me sale en la consola ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT y ya he optimizado y vaciado el cache de la aplicación, pero sigue sin funcionar.

Estas son mis rutas del web.php

```html
Route::get('/', [LoginController::class, 'index'])->name('login');
Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'store'])->name('login.store');

//Registro
Route::get('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'index'])->name('register');
Route::post('/register-user', [RegisterController::class, 'store'])->name('register.store');


//Logout
Route::post('/logout', [LogoutController::class, 'store'])->name('logout.store');

//Dashboard
Route::get('/dashboard', [VentasController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('dashboard');
Route::get('/gestion-user', [UsuariosController::class, 'index'])->name('gestionUsuarios');
Route::get('/gestion-solicitudes', [SolicitudesController::class, 'index'])->name('gestionsolicitudes');

/* Modulo de crear nueva venta */
Route::get('/nueva-venta', [VentasController::class, 'index'])->name('nueva_venta');
Route::post('/nueva-venta-crear', [VentasController::class, 'store'])->name('save_venta');

/* Modulo para mis solicitudes */
Route::get('/mis-solicitudes', [MisSolicitudesController::class, 'index'])->name('mis_solicitudes');

/* Modulo inventario */
Route::get('/inventario', [InventarioController::class, 'index'])->name('inventario');
Route::post('/inventario-crear', [InventarioController::class, 'store'])->name('inventario.store');
```

Estoy usando Laravel 10.